# regular expression join number and %

Tags: regex, node.js

I would like to connect number with '%' sign by removing spaces

Here, what I trying to do, unfortunately this doesn't work.

```
"... 14  % ...".replace(new RegExp("\\b(\\d+)\\s+%\\b",'gi'), "$1%")
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
"... 14  % ...".replace(/(\d+)\s+(%)/g,'$1$2');
```

output :  `"... 14% ..."`

it will replace all occurences of spaces between numbers and `%`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture both expressions in order to replace them, the first being the digit and the second being the number + space + %:

```
> "... 14  % ...".replace(/((\d+)\s+%)/gi, "$2%")
"... 14% ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
"... 14  % ...".replace(new RegExp("(\\d+)\\s+%",'gi'), "$1%")
```